# Can We Configure txt file in Nginx Locaton

Tags: nginx

i have server where are different type of project deploy . some project in php ans some in java war file for jboss . so i am using nginx for this layer it is working fine following configure

for Php Project

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/local/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
            root    html/static;
            expires 30d;
        }
        location ~ attendance/(js|css|images)/  {
         #  root  html;
          expires 30d;


        }
```

For Java Project

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  ncmmi02;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log   /mnt/vol1/nginx_logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            root   html;
            access_log off;
            proxy_pass http://10.20.9.13:9090;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           # proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

for java project run i have use example.com/abc (abc war file )
and php project i used example.com/attendance

Now I want to txt file to show data like example.com/rom.txt
 But in this time contain not show in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this location right below *.php one

```
location ~ *\.txt$ {
    root /path/to/your/root;
}
```